# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в выражении "недопустимо заключение контракта на срок менее чем установлено законодательством"?

Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, в приведенно вами примере присутствует сопоставление: новый срок сопоставляется со сроком, установленным законодательством. Во-вторых, это сложноподчиненное предложение: первая основа - *заключение недопустимо*, вторая основа - *установлено*. Оба факта - за запятую: *"недопустимо заключение контракта на срок менее, чем установлено законодательством"*. Можете попробовать и такой вариант: *"недопустимо заключение контракта на срок менее установленного законодательством"*.